# How to run electron app inside docker image?

Tags: reactjs, docker, electron

everyone!

I'd like to run a react-electron app (which is an offline app) inside docker image on Win10.
I used to run the app on windows by running `npm start-win` and then `npm start-electron-win`.

This is part of my package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "export BROWSER=none && export PORT=3005 && react-scripts start",
    "start-win": "set BROWSER=none && set PORT=3005 && react-scripts start",
    "start-electron": "export ELECTRON_START_URL=http://localhost:3005 && electron .",
    "start-electron-win": "set ELECTRON_START_URL=http://localhost:3005 && electron .",
  },
```

And this is Dockerfile.

```
# base image
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
CMD ["npm", "start-electron"]
```

After building and starting docker with the following commands,

```
- docker build -t offline:dev .
- docker run -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules -p 3005 --rm offline:dev
```

The building is successful without any bug and I can browse the app on `localhost:3005`,
but what I expect is to see the running electron desktop app.

Is there anyone who can help me with launching the app on docker?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you actually see on your `localhost:3005`? Any error that you can share with us?

Comment: Docker is inconvenient at best for interactive desktop applications, and the image you're building doesn't contain the application you're trying to run.  What benefit do you hope to get for running this in Docker?  (Especially since Electron already has [a well-defined distribution system](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution).)

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is called *x11 forwarding*.

Unfortunately, it'll be a little trickier to surface the underlying UI from with the running docker container than if you were using a linux distribution - docker containers are all pretty much linux based. You can't really mount the related *unix socket*

*Normally you just add the following lines to your image*

```
RUN xhost local:root
```

*and run with the socket mounted*

```
docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
```

**On the brightside,**

There appears to be a solution which is easy as installing

- VcXsrv
- Adding the `$DISPLAY` env variable with the server ip

**Follow the instructions here**

https://dev.to/darksmile92/run-gui-app-in-linux-docker-container-on-windows-host-4kde